# Express.js why to upgrade from 2.x to 3.x

Tags: node.js, express

Trying to find a rationale for upgrade, other than to stay current with API docs on express website. To my surprise I couldn't find anything on the subject. Any personal experience why 3.x is better than 2.x?

Answer (score 2):

[There are new features in Express.js 3.x.](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/wiki/New-features-in-3.x) Do you want them? Then upgrade.